# Deleting user from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

How do i delete user in ubuntu? It throws some error message.

"db2inst1" is the user I wanted to delete.

```
$sudo deluser db2inst1

Removing user `db2inst1' ...
Warning: group `db2iadm1' has no more members.
userdel: user db2inst1 is currently logged in
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/usr/sbin/userdel db2inst1' returned error code 8. Exiting.
```

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/a/385859

Comment: I think you should ask this question in http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "user db2inst1" "currently logged in"? Because the tool seems to think so. `man deluser` and `man userdel` are good reads here. Specifically, `userdel` (which is the underlying command) has a `--force` that "forces the removal of the user account, even if the user is still logged in" but warns that "this option is dangerous and may leave your system in an inconsistent state."

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
sudo userdel -r db2inst1
```